# How to indirect call php file by ajax with post type and get json return then parse it to table

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have 2 php file, one is "Db_function.php" and "index.php", "index.php" will make a function call in "Db_function.php".
I want to make a call to "index.php" by ajax, here's my code

Html file

```
<Html>
  <body>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
      <input type="button" value="Get" onclick="get()">
  </body>
</html>
```

Js file

```
function get() {
    $.ajax({ url: 'index.php',
             data: {tag:'get_backup', email:'mail@mail.com', password:'123'},
             type: 'post',
             datatype:'json'
             success: function(output) {
                          alert(output);
                      }
    });
}
```

index.php

```
/*with connect value*/
if ($tag == 'get_backup'){
            // store user
              $email = $_POST['email'];
              $password = $_POST['password'];

            $user = $db->get_backup($email, $password);
```

Db_funtion.php

```
public function get_backup($email, $password) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'") or die(mysql_error());
        // check for result 
        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $salt = $result['salt'];
            $encrypted_password = $result['encrypted_password'];
            $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
            // check for password equality
            if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
                // user authentication details are correct
                $response = array();
                $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contact_store WHERE (email ='$email' AND backup_name='$email')") or die(mysql_error());
                if (mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // contact_stores node
    $response["contact_stores"] = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
        // temp user array
        $contact_store = array();
        $contact_store["backup_name"] = $row["backup_name"];
        $contact_store["email"] = $row["email"];
        $contact_store["data"] = $row["data"];
        // push single contact_store into final response array
        array_push($response["contact_stores"], $contact_store);
    }
   // success
    $response["success"] = 1;
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no contact_stores found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No contact_stores found";
    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}

            }
        } else {
            // user not found
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Json return like this

```
{"contact_stores":[{"backup_name":"nhi@gmail.com","email":"nhi@gmail.com","data":"[]"}],"success":1}
```

But my problem is when i press get button in html file, nothing happen.
Any help for me ?

Comment: You may want to add the failure function to your `$.ajax()` call so that way you know that it failed and you can have an alert and see what happened.

Comment: Where exactly do you define this `get()` javascript function?

Comment: @svenskunganka : editted, may be it not a problem.

Comment: @AlexisWilke : can you give me some example please, i'm new in jquery.

Comment: See under `error` here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not defining the `get()` function that you provide in the input element.

Try this HTML:

```
<input id="get" type="button" value="Get">
```

with this javascript:

```
$('#get').click(function() {
    $.ajax({ url: 'index.php',
        data: {tag:'get_backup', email:'mail@mail.com', password:'123'},
        type: 'post',
        datatype:'json'
        success: function(output) {
            alert(output);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: i was defining onclick event(); and try with alert("something"), it can handel correct, may be i wrong some where in js file ?

Comment: i'm tried, it still not happen when click on button

Comment: What happens when you execute the `get()` function directly from the console? Any errors? Do you get the JSON data you're expecting?

Comment: yes, it return json data.
you can try it with this link http://mycontact.byethost7.com/android_login_api/index.php
tag:get_backup;
email:nhi@gmail.com;
password:123;
it will return :{"contact_stores":[{"backup_name":"nhi@gmail.com","email":"nhi@gmail.com","data":"[]"}],"success":1}

Comment: Access denied on that page

Comment: here HTML code: <html>
<body>
<form action="http://mycontact.byethost7.com/android_login_api/" method="post">
tag :<input type="text" name="tag">
email: <input type="text" name ="email">
pass <input type="text" name ="password">
</input>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html> _______ Please input: tag=get_backup; email=nhi@gmail.com; pass=123;